# Regex variable missing

Tags: php, regex

I don't really know how they're called, the matches between brackets but variables seems legit. Anyway I have set up a custom ( or not so much ) markup to save links into my databases so that they'll be easier to fetch and it goes like so `[url]http://www.url.com[TextToDisplay]`. I'm now trying to create a facebook-like algorithm that will detect youtube videos and embed them automatically instead of showing a link but I've come across this weird problem.

Say we have the custom url markup as:

`[url]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEGbZeaMvtg&list=RDproO6qMsR0Y[www.youtube.com]`

Then I use this `preg_replace`

```
preg_replace('/\[url\].*?youtube\.com.*?(v=(.*?)&?)?.*?\[.*?\]/i','[yt]$1[/yt]',$s);
```

and the result is

`[yt][/yt]`

Supposed to be

`[yt]WEGbZeaMvtg[/yt]`

I also tried `$2` and `$0`. `$0` turned out to be the whole string and `$2` is empty just like `$1`. My question si why are those "Regex variables" empty?

Sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e408254542d0bbea2f5635ba2d3c8d3a23f844eb

Comment: I believe the 'matches between brackets' are called captures.

Comment: @shennan got the note

Comment: do you really need to have the v= part optional? Its easy to do if you force the v= bit to be there. - as all of the answers do

Comment: @OGHaza that's what I just noticed and thought to myself, am I retarded.. /facepalm

Comment: @php_nub_qq, just fyi, your original code worked if you removed the question marks in `(v=(.*?)&?)?` and got the value from `$2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\[url\].*?youtube\.com.*?v=(.*?)[\&|].*?\[.*?\]/is', '[yt]$1[/yt]', $s);
```

Comment: Hey, can you explain what this does exactly `[\&|]`? Because I'm having trouble matching two links in one string, as well as an url that doesn't have `&` in it :/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one. It also extracts the second part (the name between brackets):

```
preg_replace('/\[url\].*?youtube\.com.*\?v=([^&]*)&[^[]*\[([^]]*)\]/i','[yt]$1 -> $2[/yt]',$str);
```

Observe how [^&]* indicates a block of text that does **not** contains the `&` char.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one that worked for me:

```
$str = '[url]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEGbZeaMvtg&list=RDproO6qMsR0Y[www.youtube.com]';

$str = preg_replace('/\[url\].*?youtube\.com.*?v=.*?(.*)\&.*\[www\.youtube\.com\]/i','[yt]$1[/yt]',$str);

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple sequences of lazy matching and a few optional sections, so what your regex is doing is:

```
/\[url\].*?youtube\.com.*?(v=(.*?)&?)?.*?\[.*?\]/i
                       ^^^ match as few as possible, done: 0

                                     ^ optional, done, skipped

                                      ^^^ match as few as possible, done: '/watch?v=WEGbZeaMvtg&list=RDproO6qMsR0Y' will match here
```

You need to write your regex so that there is only one possible solution. In your case you could use for example negated charater classes to accomplish that.

[To illustrate](http://codepad.org/tCc22ZzO).